# Programmatic UINavigationController and segue away

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

In my code I need to go through a navigation hierarchy, which is why I have a `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.

If the user tabs on a cell and there is a next level, I create the same `UIViewController` again and push it on the `UINavigationController`. This works fine.

But when I reach the end of the hierarchy and try to `performSegueWithIdentifier`, to go to a different controller to see the details, the app crashes and says

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
 reason: 'Receiver (<myproject.MenuController: 0x7fb2e0ea9ef0>)
has no segue with identifier 'showDetail''
```

However I checked InterfaceBuilder, all fine.
Interestingly, If I **don't push a next level of navigation** and perform the segue to the new controller directly, all works well.

I also tried to push the new controller, like I'm doing with the navigation, but then it tries to access the new controllers delegates which strangely are `nil` and crashes.

Somebody know how to do this?

Complete code (inside MenuContoller)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
//self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
let clickedCell = self.tableViewItems[indexPath.row]
print("Selected \(clickedCell.itemID)")
// Check if subview has children, then we push a deeper level on the navigation controller
if (menuItems.filter{$0.parentID == clickedCell.itemID}.count > 0) {
  let subNavigationController = MenuController()
  // Set the currentNavigationItemID for the new view controller
  subNavigationController.currentNavigationItemID = clickedCell.itemID
  subNavigationController.title = clickedCell.itemDisplayName
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subNavigationController, animated: true)
} else {
  // Load new Controller to show details
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
//      let subNavigationController = ProductListViewController()
//      subNavigationController.currentCategoryID = clickedCell.itemID
//      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subNavigationController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `MenuController` has not been created from the Storyboard, so it has no segues attached to it.

You need to ask the Storyboard to create the `MenuController`, so instead of:

```
let subNavigationController = MenuController()
```

you need:

```
let subNavigationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuControllerID")
```

For this to work, the storyboard ID must be set in the *Identity Inspector* to `"menuControllerID"` for `MenuController`.